College student gets involved with his professor's wife
So I'm looking for this movie that's about a college student (I think) that was given an assignment from his professor. At some point in the movie, the student gets to go to the professor's house to help with the assignment or something like that, and the guy notices his professor's wife. He gets interested in her quite much.
More into the movie, the student somehow gets into the professor's house and stalks them both having sex. He is seen writing down some notes in a notebook. Eventually the guy has an affair with his professor's wife and they have sex and I think the professor finds out.
I only saw the trailer of this movie, and I need it for a psychology project. I think it's the perfect movie to analyze based on what I saw from the trailer long ago, but I need the title of the film. From what I remember from the trailer, the title had either the word house or mansion on it, or had a reference or a name of a place/building. Please help me find it! Thank you! 

In which year, did you watch the trailer?

I think you're after Francois Ozon's In the House from 2012 with Kristin Scott Thomas and Emmanuelle Seigner:

A sixteen-year-old boy insinuates himself into the house of a fellow student from his literature class and writes about it in essays for his French teacher. Faced with this gifted and unusual pupil, the teacher rediscovers his enthusiasm for his work, but the boy's intrusion will unleash a series of uncontrollable events.

See if the trailer rings any bells:




I think you're looking for the movie
My Teacher's Wife

the story follows the travails of Southport High School senior Todd
  Boomer (Jason London) whose lifelong dream of going to Harvard is
  derailed by his hard-nosed calculus teacher Mr. Mueller (Christopher
  McDonald). When Todd enlists the tutoring help of the sexy and
  mysterious Vicki (Tia Carrere), things go from bad to worse.

